# What happens to engines when mixed with wrong gas

Tags: lawn-mower

I wanted to know what would happen if I put regular gas in a 2 stroke engine and 2 stroke mix gas into a 4 stroke.

Comment: Then you should read http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/43816/what-could-happen-if-i-used-4-cycle-fuel-in-a-2-cycle-engine and http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/what-could-happen-if-i-use-2-cycle-fuel-in-a-4-cycle-engine

Comment: The 2-stroke would seize (eventually) and the 4-stroke would produce smoke and foul it's plugs.